# Run self._cr.execute on Compute Field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

On Odoo 12, Im trying run `self._cr.execute` on compute but return me `Null`, I tried domain and is working but because the Query i will use is complex i need to do it with SQL Query.

```
    _inherit ='purchase.order.line'  

    partner1 = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Vendor 1', compute='_compute_vendors', copy = True, store=True, readonly= False)
    partner2 = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Vendor 2', compute='_compute_vendors', copy = True, store=True, readonly= False)
    partner3 = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Vendor 3', compute='_compute_vendors', copy = True, store=True, readonly= False)

    @api.depends('product_id')
    def _compute_vendors(self):
        vendors = []
        vendors.append(self._cr.execute("""SELECT partner_id FROM purchase_order_line"""))
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute return `None`, to retrieve the selected records you can use fetchall:

```
  # first execute the query
  self._cr.execute("""SELECT partner_id FROM purchase_order_line""")
  # fetc rows
  vendors = [r[0] for r in self._cr.fetchall()]
```